# Error while parsing Binary Files

Tags: java, pdfbox, apache-tika

I am trying to parse pdf file using Apache Tika after upgrading PDFBOX version to 1.6.0... And I started getting this error for few pdf files.
Any suggestions?

```
java.io.IOException: expected='endstream' actual='' org.apache.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream@3a72d4e5
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSStream(BaseParser.java:439)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseObject(PDFParser.java:552)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:184)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1088)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1053)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:74)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:135)
        at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:357)
        at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.BinaryParser.parse(BinaryParser.java:37)
        at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.handleBinary(WebCrawler.java:223)
        at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.processPage(WebCrawler.java:461)
        at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.run(WebCrawler.java:129)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
     WARN [Crawler 2] Did not found XRef object at specified startxref position 0
```

---

And this is my code.

```
        if (page.isBinary()) {
                        handleBinary(page, curURL);
                    }
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            public int handleBinary(Page page, WebURL curURL) {
                    try {
                        binaryParser.parse(page.getBinaryData());
                        page.setText(binaryParser.getText());
                        handleMetaData(page, binaryParser.getMetaData());



                        //System.out.println(" pdf url " +page.getWebURL().getURL());
                        //System.out.println("Text" +page.getText());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                    return PROCESS_OK;
                }
```

---

```
        public class BinaryParser {

            private String text;
            private Map<String, String> metaData;

            private Tika tika;

            public BinaryParser() {
                tika = new Tika();
            }

            public void parse(byte[] data) {
                InputStream is = null;
                try {
                    is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                    text = null;
                    Metadata md = new Metadata();
                    metaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    text = tika.parseToString(is, md).trim();
                    processMetaData(md);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
                }
            }

            public String getText() {
                return text;
            }

            public void setText(String text) {
                this.text = text;
            }


            private void processMetaData(Metadata md){
                if ((getMetaData() == null) || (!getMetaData().isEmpty())) {
                    setMetaData(new HashMap<String, String>());
                }
                for (String name : md.names()){
                    getMetaData().put(name.toLowerCase(), md.get(name));
                }
            }

            public Map<String, String> getMetaData() {
                return metaData;
            }

            public void setMetaData(Map<String, String> metaData) {
                this.metaData = metaData;
            }

        }
```

---

```
    public class Page {

        private WebURL url;

        private String html;

        // Data for textual content
        private String text;

        private String title;

        private String keywords;
        private String authors;
        private String description;
        private String contentType;
        private String contentEncoding;

        // binary data (e.g, image content)
        // It's null for html pages
        private byte[] binaryData;

        private List<WebURL> urls;

        private ByteBuffer bBuf;

        private final static String defaultEncoding = Configurations
                .getStringProperty("crawler.default_encoding", "UTF-8");

        public boolean load(final InputStream in, final int totalsize,
                final boolean isBinary) {
            if (totalsize > 0) {
                this.bBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(totalsize + 1024);
            } else {
                this.bBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(PageFetcher.MAX_DOWNLOAD_SIZE);
            }
            final byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            double finished = 0;
            try {
                while ((len = in.read(b)) != -1) {
                    if (finished + b.length > this.bBuf.capacity()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    this.bBuf.put(b, 0, len);
                    finished += len;
                }
            } catch (final BufferOverflowException boe) {
                System.out.println("Page size exceeds maximum allowed.");
                return false;
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }

            this.bBuf.flip();
            if (isBinary) {
                binaryData = new byte[bBuf.limit()];
                bBuf.get(binaryData);
            } else {
                this.html = "";
                this.html += Charset.forName(defaultEncoding).decode(this.bBuf);
                this.bBuf.clear();
                if (this.html.length() == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    public boolean isBinary() {
        return binaryData != null;
    }

    public byte[] getBinaryData() {
        return binaryData;
    }
```

Comment: Do these PDF files open up ok in anything else? That error looks like it might be caused by corrupted PDFs

Comment: @Gagravarr, yes I am able to open all those pdf... they are not corrupted..!! Something else is wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you don't accidentally truncate the PDF document when you load it into the binary buffer in the Page class?

There are multiple potential problems in your `Page.load()` method. To start with, the `finished + b.length > this.bBuf.capacity()` should be `finished + len > this.bBuf.capacity()` since the read() method could have returned fewer than b.length bytes. Also, are you sure that the totalsize argument you give is accurate? Finally, it could be that the given document is larger than the `MAX_DOWNLOAD_SIZE` limit.

Comment: Do we have any solution for this issue?